# When I make post request form react the I recieve an empty body in the back end. I do not understand why

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, http-post

I have been trying to make a post request using react to a node.js backend. Making post requests with postman works fine and the get requests work fine as well. Here is my react code. No matter what I try the req.body recieved is always empty in the node backend.

```
import axios from "axios";

class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            userId:'',
            title:'',
            body:''
        }
    }

    changeHandler = (e) =>{
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }


    submitHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
        axios.post("http://localhost:2000/api",this.state).then(response=>{console.log(response)}).catch(error=>(console.log(error)))

    }


    render() {
        const {userId,title,body} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="userId" value={userId} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="title" value={title} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="body" value={body} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PostForm
```

Comment: From code side it looks fine. Check you backend if you are using nodejs then you might need to use `bodyparser` middleware

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I already use body-parser in my back end const `bodyParser = require("body-parser")` and `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));`.  But I am wondering, can it be a backend problem since posts from postman work fine?

Comment: did you use ```app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));``` or just body parser for the urlencoded format

Comment: Log in backend and also check api path. From frontend side it looks ok

Comment: @JithinZachariah first of all you are an angel sent from heaven! Second of all why does this work and why isn't it mentioned anywhere else? And third why do my posts from postman not work?

Comment: Can I post that as the answer? Did your problem resolve?

Comment: @JithinZachariah Yes is works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data can be sent to the backend as URL encoded format or as raw JSON format you have to handle both cases as shown below.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '10mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000
  })
);
```

Comment: You sir are a hero - thanks! I have been tackling this issue for 4 hours now and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

When working with express, by default the `req` object which represents data or informations coming from your client application doesn't have a body attribute, and that's the reason why your the body attribute is empty.

So if you want to access data sent by your `client application` through an `http request`,you should add a middleware function that can parse, inspect the incoming request and takes the whatever data sent by the client via a `post` or `put method http verb`, and add it in the `body attribute` of the `request object`.That function is executed before your route `handler`.

If your sending data in a `JSON format` should add the following `middleware`:

`app.use(express.json())` and your code will look like this :

```
const express=require('express');

const app=express();

app.use(express.json())
```

If data is coming in a `urlencoded format` where you've got a form like this `<form method='post' action='http://yourserver/routes_handler'>...</form>` without making an ajax request, you will instead add the following middleware:

`app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})) //it can be true or false depending on what you wan to achieve`.

If data can come in the 2 formats then you'll use the both middlewares and your code will look like this:

```
const express=require('express');

const app=express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
```

You don't have to install a third party package like `body-parser` in order to add the middleware it's already a built-in feature in `express`